# Como fazer a remoção de um elemento de um html por meio do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
var arrayTeste = [];
var arrayTesteII = [];

arrayTeste.forEach((list) => {
  mostraNaTela(list);
});

function adicionarFilme() {
  var elementoRecebido = document.getElementById("filme").value;

  if (elementoRecebido.endsWith(".jpg") || elementoRecebido.endsWith(".png")) {
    arrayTeste.push(elementoRecebido);
    mostraImgNaTela(elementoRecebido);
  } else {
    alert("Por favor, adicione um link de Imagem, com final '.jpg' ou '.png'");
  }

  var limpaCampoLink = "";
  document.getElementById("filme").value = limpaCampoLink;
}

function adicionaTitulo() {
  var elementoTituloRecebido = document.getElementById("titulo").value;

  arrayTesteII.push(elementoTituloRecebido);
  mostraSubTituloNaTela(elementoTituloRecebido);

  var limpaCampoTitulo = "";
  document.getElementById("titulo").value = limpaCampoTitulo;
}

function mostraImgNaTela(link) {
  var preparaDiv = document.getElementById("listaFilmes");
  var mandaLink = "<img src=" + link + ">";

  preparaDiv.innerHTML = preparaDiv.innerHTML + mandaLink;
}

function mostraSubTituloNaTela(palavra) {
  var preparaDiv = document.getElementById("listaFilmes");
  var mandaTitulo = "<h2>" + palavra + "</h2>";

  preparaDiv.innerHTML = preparaDiv.innerHTML + mandaTitulo;
}
```

quero remover o link que é adicionado, para retirar a imagem da tela e adicionar novos links.
tentei o .innerHTML e o .innerHTML.remove() mas não deu certo pois deletava a  do html mas não deletava as imagens. alguém poderia me auxiliar ?

Answer (score 0):

Podes criar um array com os elementos HTML. De cada vez que adicionas renderizas todos os elementos. Para remover basta fazer splice() no array.

```
var elementos = [];

function mostraImgNaTela(link) {
  var mandaLink = "<img src=" + link + ">";
  elementos.push(mandaLink);
  mostrarFilmes();
}

function mostraSubTituloNaTela(palavra) {
  var mandaTitulo = "<h2>" + palavra + "</h2>";
  elementos.push(mandaTitulo);
  mostrarFilmes();
}

function mostrarFilmes() {
    var preparaDiv = document.getElementById("listaFilmes");
    preparaDiv.innerHTML = elementos.join();
}

function removerElemento(index) {
    elementos.splice(index, 1);
    mostrarFilmes();
}
```